the register assignment collision across shader stages in dx12
My vertex shader use cbuffer 'A' it get assign to register b0. At the same time, my pixel shader use cbuffer 'B' and after compilation it get assign to the same register b0.
As i can see, in order to resolve the collision i have a few options.
1.) use old school binding model. One descriptor table per stage ( VS / PS... ) with D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY flag.
2.) explicit register assignment in HLSL ( : register( b0 )... etc ). One descriptor table for all stages.
3.) bindless rendering
IMHO, all three is not a option for me.
So, the question is. It’s not about multi thread compilation. Is there anyway to compile HLSL for specific shader stage with regards to previous shader stage inorder to resolve register collision?
My vertex shader use cbuffer 'A' it get assign to register b0. When time gets to compile pixel shader, somehow to pass to compiler a memory blob from previous stage, then cbuffer 'B' will get assign to the next free register b1 in my case.
In this case, i can put all my handles in one descriptor table for all stages.

Dx12 force you to provide all shaders to create the pipeline. Why the hell it does not validate the registers across shader stages  and allows to provide shaders with register collisions. And why there is no shader pipeline?

I asked the same question on dxc GitHub repo. They keep silence. As for me its real pain in the ass.

Another big annoying idea, we don’t need annotations on variables, lets get rid of them. Common, who told you that?
